# ERROR: java.lang.ClassCastException: frsf.isi.died.tp.modelo.productos.Video cannot be cast to [Lfrsf.isi.died.tp.modelo.productos.Video;

Tags: java

Tengo un problema de casteo (al parecer). Este es el error que me devuelve eclipse:
java.lang.ClassCastException: frsf.isi.died.tp.modelo.productos.Video cannot be cast to [Lfrsf.isi.died.tp.modelo.productos.Video;

Estoy intentado recuperar mis objetos de clase "Video" que están guardados en un fichero. Cuando intento crear un Arreglo de "Video[]" para poder recuperar los elementos del fichero me sale dicho error. Dejo la parte del código dónde se encentra el error:

```
    public static void guardarVideo(Video unVideo) {
    Video video = unVideo;


    try {

        ObjectOutputStream  escribiendo = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("F:/JAVA Projectos/taller01/Datos/Videos.txt",true));

        escribiendo.writeObject(video);

        escribiendo.close();

        ObjectInputStream leyendo = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("F:/JAVA Projectos/taller01/Datos/Videos.txt"));
        //Este es el error 
        Object[] recuperado = (Video[]) leyendo.readObject();

        leyendo.close();

        for(Object v : recuperado) {
            System.out.println(v);

        }

            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la forma de castear no es la correcta, de por sí el método devuelve un objeto pero no quiere decir que tengas que hacer referencia a la clase Object. Tienes que hacer referencia con la misma clase que estás casteando.

```
Video[] video = (Video[])leyendo.readObject();
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la ayuda. Cuando hago eso mismo que tú me propones me aparece este error:
 java.lang.ClassCastException: elementos.Video cannot be cast to [Lelementos.Video; at elementos.Video.guardarVideo

Se puede observar que aparece una "L" en el segundo elemento. Tienes alguna idea de por qué puede ser?

Comment: No te podría decir con exactitud pero quisiera saber si es que hacemos referencia a una sola clase Video, porque esa "L" debe salir de alguna mala escritura que hayas hecho, revisa bien la estructura del proyecto. Saludos!!

Comment: Hacemos referencia a la misma clase Video (existe una sola). Revisé la escritura muchas veces y probé varias maneras y siempre me sale el mismo error.  La verdad me dejó con una intriga enorme..